# Best way to verify text in a table is between 2 specified items - Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following table and I am wanting to verify that "Vendor Assignment Expired" is in between "Vendor Accepted Assignment" and "Vendor Declined Assignment". What would be the best way to go about doing this?

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; visibility: inherit;" id="x:1011327536.4:mkr:dataTbl.hdn" mkr="dataTbl.hdn">
  <tbody id="x:1011327536.12:mkr:rows:nw:1" class="ig_ListItem igg_ListItem" nw="1" mkr="rows">
    <tr id="x:1011327536.13:adr:0:tag:" tag="" adr="0" type="row">
      <td class="grdCell" style="width:46%;" idx="0" adr="0" type="cell"> Update Disclosure Date </td>
    </tr>
    <!--[600001]-->
    <tr id="x:1011327536.13:adr:1:tag:" class="ig_ListAlt igg_ListAlt" tag="" adr="1" type="row">
      <td class="grdCell" idx="0" adr="0" type="cell"> Vendor Accepted Assignment </td>
    </tr>
    <!--[101020]-->
    <tr id="x:1011327536.13:adr:2:tag:" tag="" adr="2" type="row">
      <td class="grdCell" idx="0" adr="0" type="cell"> Vendor Assignment Expired </td>
    </tr>
    <!--[900101]-->
    <tr id="x:1011327536.13:adr:3:tag:" class="ig_ListAlt igg_ListAlt" tag="" adr="3" type="row">
      <td class="grdCell" idx="0" adr="0" type="cell"> Vendor Declined Assignment </td>
    </tr>
    <!--[900102]-->
    <tr id="x:1011327536.13:adr:4:tag:" tag="" adr="4" type="row">
      <td class="grdCell" idx="0" adr="0" type="cell"> Conditionally Declined </td>
    </tr>
```

I know I can loop through each item like this:

```
List<WebElement> row = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector(".igg_ListItem > tr > td:nth-child(1)"));
for(WebElement el : row) 
{
    el.getText();
}
```

I'm just not sure how to capture the values to perform the assertion that the text displays between the other 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this -

```
 List<WebElement> row = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector(".igg_ListItem > tr > td:nth-child(1)"));
    for (int i =0; i<row.size();i++) {
    String status = row.get(i).getText();

    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Vendor Assignment Expired")) {
        if (row.get(i-1).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Vendor Accepted Assignment") 
                && row.get(i+1).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Vendor Declined Assignment"))
        System.out.println("Yes it between those values");
        break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works! Cheers!

Comment: What is the "i" supposed to be here? This doesn't compile as-is. It looks like it should be the row number, but everything I'm trying to resolve the compilation errors is not working.

Comment: My mistake. Corrected now

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below:
Get next column Text and assert it with expected value.

`String declinedAssignment = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[text()=/"Vendor Assignment Expired/"]]//following-sibling::tr/td")).getText();`

Get previous column Text and assert it with expected value.

`String acceptedAssignment = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[text()=/"Vendor Assignment Expired/"]]//preceding-sibling::tr/td")).getText();`

Comment: Gave you an up-vote because this does work. I am trying to avoid xpath, however. I will keep this one in mind though if I need something similar in the future